# Are there any guidelines for how similar an app's interface can be to Siri?

Tags: ios, user-interface, siri

I'd like to develop an app that has a voice command interface similar to Siri's.  (I know, very hard to do, lots of voice commands to code in, but, hopefully, this app won't require too many of them).  Anyway, I read somewhere that having an interface too similar to Siri's will keep your app out of the store, so I was wondering what constitutes 'too similar'?

Comment: You might actually worry about too similar in functionality more than the overall look. It's usually preferred to make an app look more native looking but they don't want you to replace their core functionality so making a very similar interface might be a red flag.

Comment: Well, no, I wouldn't want to replace Siri, just mimic it a bit to accomplish a different set of tasks.  Red flag there?